# How to get join results as an array of objects in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, laravel-5

I have been working on a personal project where users can rate different shops. Among many, I have two tables schemas that I am working on.

Table: Shops

1. id
2. shop_name
3. user_id (shops belongs to a user)

Table : Ratings

1. id
2. shop_id (foreign_key)
3. rating
4. user_id

Now I want to fetch all the shops and its corresponding ratings using SQL join.

```
 $shop = Shop::leftJoin('ratings', 'ratings.shop_id', '=', 'shops.id')
    ->select('shops.*', 'ratings.rating')->get();
    return response($shop);
```

When I do this I get response but the it is repeated for each ratings on the same shop.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "manjil",
        "rating": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "manjil",
        "rating": 5
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "manjil",
        "rating": 2
    }]
```

What I really want is :

```
        [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "manjil",
            "rating": [4,5,2]
        }]
```

Please Laravel geeks, help :)

Comment: try `->groupBy('rating');` before `->get();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the easy solution would be to use the relation directly

```
$shops = Shop::with('ratings')->get();
//possible mapping here
return response($shops);
```

you can afterwards map the ratings to get only an array of the field `rating`

```
$shops = $shops->map(function ($shop) {
    $shop->ratings = $shop->ratings->pluck('rating')->all();
    return $shop;
});
```